# Setting up MySQL 5.6 with Memcache fails without error

Tags: mysql, memcached, mysql-5.6

I am trying to setup MySQL 5.6 with the memcached plugin enabled. I followed the procedure on the [mysql website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html) and a couple of other tutorials [2](http://opensourcedba.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/mysql-5-6-innodb-and-memcached/), [3](http://chipersoft.com/p/MySQL-via-Memcache/) that I found online. Specifically, as per [2](http://opensourcedba.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/mysql-5-6-innodb-and-memcached/), this should be really simple to setup and test.

I am trying to verify that the setup works as expected using telnet. When I set the value of a key from telnet, I get the return status of STORED. I can even fetch the value immediately from memcache. However, when I login into the DB, I do not see the new row. I don't see any errors in the logs either. *"show plugins"* shows that the daemon_memcached plugin is enabled.

[Edited]

Actually, things don't even the other way. I added a new row into the demo_test table and tried fetching it through the memcache interface. That didn't work either.

Any pointers about how to go about identifying what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The memcache integration in MySQL communicates directly with the InnoDB storage engine, not the higher MySQL "server layer."  As such, changes to table data through this interface do not invalidate queries against the table that have been stored in the query cache.  This is in contrast to normal operations through the SQL interface, where any change to a table's data will immediately evict any and all results held from the query cache for queries against that table, without regard to whether or not the change to the table data actually invalidated each specific query impacted.

Repeat your query, but instead of `SELECT`, use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`.  If you get the result you expect, this is the explanation.

Once you have established that this is the cause, you will find that any SQL query that does an insert, delete, or update against the table will also have the effect of making memcache-changed data visible to `SELECT` queries, without the need for adding the `SQL_NO_CACHE` directive, and this will hold true even when the insert, delete, or update does not directly impact the *rows* in question, so long as it modifies something in the *table* in question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this didn't solve the problem. I tried another test wherein I added a row to the table using SQL and tried to get that value from memcache. That didn't work either. I edited my main question above with this info.

Answer (score 0):

Duh!! There was already a memcached instance running on port 11211. Unfortunately, mysql doesn't error out in this situation. When I was using telnet to connect to port 11211, I was reaching the existing memcached instance. It was storing/retrieving values that it had seen but wasn't communicating with MySQL.

I stopped the existing memcached instance and restarted mysql. I am now able to connect to port 11211. Using telnet, when I do a "get", I get back values from the db. Also, when I set new values from telnet, they get reflected in the DB (and can be retrieved using SQL).